# add www only if is no subdomain present using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to automatically add www if there´s no subdomain in the url

```
https://example.com => https://www.example.com
http://test.example.com => http://test.example.com (no change)
```

it also will be nice to make it work for both http and https.

this is what I have so far

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%2%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Will this always rewrite to https, for every possible combination?